# Gatsby: How do you create a dynamic nav that marks the current page as active?

Tags: navigation, graphql, gatsby

I've been struggling with this for hours.

The [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-dynamic-navigation/) does not mark the current page as active.

More context: I'm using a WordPress implementation as the back-end for my Gatsby site, so a WordPress API focused answer would be appreciated.

If you use the example given in the Gatsby documentation as a base for your answer, I can probably extrapolate from that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `activeClassName` or for more power the `getProps` property on the `<Link />` component (as it's a thin wrapper around `@reach/router`'s Link component).

The documentation you're looking for is here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/

Comment: Excellent. I was about to ask how I use that information to apply an `aria-current="page"` attribute when the link is active but it looks like `activeClassName="isActive"` also adds `aria-current="page"` automatically.